# Get Postgres dump from a database hosted in a different server through Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I'd like to get the equivalent of pg_dump inside django to fetch table details from the database hosted in a different server. I know of call_command where i can use call_command('dumpdata',stdout=f) to dump my data to a file but it requires the database to be in the same machine.

Also, i know i can use the sub_process to run the below code.

```
pg_dump --host="" -U username -W -d database  -t tablename> outputfile.sql
```

But i am looking for a method using Django.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to make sure you have access to the database hosted in a different server, then you need to install celery(http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html) in your django application. In your django application,you should wrap your pg_dump command in the celery tasks queue to get the data from other database.

Comment: Celery is a whole separate task queuing system, dude.